# Is it possible to get some data from google play through other app without opening google play? android tv

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv

I need to get an url for Application banner which is not installed on my device android TV. Is it possible to get app banner from google play if I know the url to the google play of app? For example I need Spotify Android TV app banner but it is not installed on my device.